# What should be the installation order for the Dual Boot Windows 10 and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, windows-10, partitioning

I was learning how to create a Dual Boot (Windows 10 and Windows 7) in a 250GB HDD.
There were two partitions in the 250GB HDD. **I installed Windows 7 first** and then windows 10. The Windows installation processes were successful and I could switch between Windows 7 and Windows 10.
But when I logged on Windows 7, I could see there were two main drives, one was C drive and the other D drive. When I double clicked My Computer in Windows 7, I could access the Drive D which Windows 10 had been installed, and I could see and access all the folders (Windows.old, PerLogs, Windows, etc.) in the D drive.

Does this mean that I have done something wrong in the dual-boot setup?
Thank you

Comment: General Rule of Thumb:"Install the newer version of Windows last."  What you describe is normal, its not clear, what you believe to be strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the primary partition where you've originally installed the first OS does not hide the secondary partition by default.
If the dual boot works and you want their respective OS to see their respective drive, you can hide the partition

In Win7 > right-click Computer > Manage
Storage > Disk Management
Right-click DriveD in the console > Change Drive Letters and Paths
Remove the Drive D

To re-establish the connection to this drive while you're boot into the WIN7 OS, you can use the same step and Add Drive D

Comment: Thank you for the help, Lex. I have done the changes according to your answer. It works, but I am wondering if it is possible to hide the D drive during windows installation or the Dual-boot setup?

Comment: I don't think you can/should hide the D drive during windows installation unless it's unplugged or disabled in the bios. The OS will need to identify all the hardware for the installation to make a sound choice on where to install it.